# I need help creating a function type declaration based on variadic template class parameters

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I would like to create a function type declaration within a variadic template class. The function needs to take parameters corresponding to the template parameter list. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to constrain all but the last parameter, in the function parameter list, to be const references. The last function parameter needs to be a non-const reference.

Below is some code which hopefully demonstrates the challenge I'm trying to overcome. I have chosen `SomeClass<int, int, double>` to use in this simple example, but both the template types and number of template arguments will change...

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename First, typename ...Rest>
struct SomeClass
{
  using Fn = void (*)(First&, Rest&...);
  using FnConst = void (*)(const First&, const Rest&...);
  //using FnLastNonConst = HELP;
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << typeid(SomeClass<int, int, double>::Fn).name() << std::endl;
  std::cout << typeid(SomeClass<int, int, double>::FnConst).name() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the generate output, when piped through `c++filt -t`...

```
void (*)(int&, int&, double&)
void (*)(int const&, int const&, double const&)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to define `FnLastNonConst` such that it would generate...

```
void (*)(int const&, int const&, double&)
```

I have attempted numerous recursive solutions involving std::conditional and helper classes, but I can't figure out how to bring that together into the top-most function type declaration. I've reached my limits and I'm starting to think this might not be possible. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using extra layer seems required, for example:

```
template<typename Tuple, typename Seq>
struct Helper;

template<typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct Helper<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
  using type = void (*) (std::conditional_t<(1 + Is) == sizeof...(Is), Ts&, const Ts&>...);
};

template<typename ...Ts>
struct SomeClass
{
  using Fn = void (*)(Ts&...);
  using FnConst = void (*)(const Ts&...);
  using FnLastNonConst = typename Helper<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>>::type;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j13KWKW5a)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to adjust the boilerplate to make it perfectly suit your needs (the cumbersome part, I know) but as for the basic skeleton it can look more-less like this:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail
{

    template<typename Tuple, std::size_t ...IDX>
    constexpr auto repack_tuple_in_cref(const Tuple t, std::index_sequence<IDX...>)
    -> decltype(std::tie(std::get<IDX>(t)...));

    template<typename Last, typename ...Args>
    constexpr auto add_tuple_tail_ref(Last&&,  std::tuple<Args...>)
    -> std::tuple<Args..., Last&>;

    template<typename ...Args>
    constexpr auto void_func_ptr_with_args(std::tuple<Args...>)
    -> void (*)(Args...);
}

template<typename ...Args>
constexpr auto func_with_last_non_const()
{
    using ValT = std::tuple<Args...>;
    using Last = std::tuple_element_t<std::tuple_size_v<ValT>-1, ValT>;
    using ConstRefAddedT = decltype(
        detail::repack_tuple_in_cref(
            std::declval<ValT>(),
            std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<ValT>-1>{}));
    using LastNonConstRefT = decltype(
        detail::add_tuple_tail_ref(
            std::declval<Last>(), std::declval<ConstRefAddedT>())
    );

    using FptrT = decltype(detail::void_func_ptr_with_args(
        std::declval<LastNonConstRefT>()));

    return FptrT{};
}


template <typename First, typename ...Args>
struct S
{
    using Fn = decltype(func_with_last_non_const<First, Args...>());
};




int main(int, char const*[])
{
    using F = typename S<int, char, double>::Fn;

    static_assert(
      std::is_same_v<
        F,
        void (*)(const int&, const char&, double&)>,
    "");
    return 0;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zEnGxea37

The principle behind it is quite straightforward once broken down into separate steps: put all the the types is a tuple, add the consts/refs/whatever to the types needed, put it together into a tuple again and unpack its inner types into a function pointer params in the end.
Also I've assumed you are using C++17 or newer, I'm not sure if that code compiles on earlier versions of the language.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more approach to achieve this other than the approach suggested by @alagner, but this might not be the best way to achieve the solution.

One can declare one more function template type as follows

```
template<typename OneMoreFirst, typename ...OneMoreRest>
using FnCustom = void (*) (OneMoreFirst&, OneMoreRest&...);
```

Usage:

```
typeid(SomeClass<int, int, double>::FnCustom<const int, const int, double>).name()
```

And pass the types with const-ness and non-const-ness as needed.

For complete example please refer to: https://godbolt.org/z/v778hG31e

Thanks